# Does the residue map Res commutes with d?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $M$ be a complex manifold of dimension $n$, and $D$ be a smooth hypersurface. Let $\varphi$ be a $C^{\infty}$ $ k$-form on $M \backslash D$. We s**ay that $\varphi$ has logarithmic singularities on $D$** if for any point $m_{0} \in D$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $m_{0}$ in $M$, where $D$ is defined by a local equation $s=0$ :
$$
D \cap U=\{m \in U \mid s(m)=0\}
$$
and the form $\varphi$ can be written in $U \backslash D$ as
$$\varphi=\frac{d s}{s} \wedge \omega+\theta,$$
where $\omega$ and $\theta$ are $C^{\infty}$ forms on $U$ of degree $k-1$ and $k$ respectively.

In   p.104  of  the  book  Ancona--Gaveau,  *Differential forms on singular varieties. De Rham and Hodge theory simplified*,  the Lemma 6.2 reads: **Res commutes with $d: \operatorname{Res} d \varphi=d \operatorname{Res} \varphi$.**

**Here is the proof of Lemma 6.2:**

(ii) We write $\varphi$ as $\varphi=\frac{d s}{s} \wedge \omega+\theta$. Then
$$
d \varphi=\frac{d s}{s} \wedge d \omega+d \theta.
$$
Hence $\operatorname{Res} d \varphi=\left.d \omega\right|_{D}=d \operatorname{Res} \varphi$.

**My opinion:**
According to the above argument, this should be reduced to show
$$d(ds/s)=0$$
(in the current sense; outside $D$ this is of course right. But over the whole of $U$ it is a current calculation).
One can easily check that  $d(ds/s)=0$ is equivalent to $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}( \frac{1}{z})=0$. However  I'm pretty sure that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}( \frac{1}{z})=\pi \delta_{0}$$
via the generalized Cauchy integral formula, here we view $s$ as the coordinate function $z_1$ and
the Dirac measure $\delta_0$ is w.r.t. the $z_1$ plane.

**Question:  Has anyone seen this result that Res commutes with $d$ in any other book or paper?**(I think this result may be wrong)

Any clues is appreciated!

Comment: As a rational function $\partial/\partial \bar{z}(1/z)=0$. So $d(1/z)=0$ as a differential 1-form. This is how we perform derivative in differential geometry. The equality you wrote with Dirac measure is a different interpretation of $d$.

Comment: @AGlearner Thank you,  how to show  $\partial/\partial \bar{z}(1/z)=0$ as a rational function?  Can you explain that a little bit more or  recommend  some references?

Comment: The book--Chris A. M. Peters · Joseph H. M. Steenbrink  Mixed Hodge  Structures--also gives this result that Res commutes with $d$.